# VBA - Set Range from Max in range

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is a way to set a range after using the `WorksheetFunction.Max` function.  So, if the range max is 12/31/2015, can I revert the value back to a cell range,  i.e. `"D10"`.  This is the code that I have so far.

Sub NetValue()

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long, rngCell As Range, rngRange As Range, _
lngMin As Long, lngMax As Long, lngPreviousRow As Long, _
raw As Worksheet, data As Worksheet, dLRow As Double, endDate As Double, _
r As Range, n As Long

lngLastRow = lastRow(column_to_check:=2)

Set raw = Worksheets("Raw")
Set data = Worksheets("Data")
Set rngRange = raw.Range(raw.Cells(2, 1), raw.Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 1))
dLRow = data.Range("A1", data.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

raw.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Insert
raw.Range("C:E").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

For Each rngCell In rngRange

    If Len(rngCell) > 0 Then

        If lngPreviousRow > 0 And (rngCell.Row - 1 <> lngPreviousRow) Then
            raw.Cells(lngPreviousRow, 10) = s.Cells(n).Offset(0, 6)
        End If

        If (rngCell.Row = 1) Or lngPreviousRow = (rngCell.Row - 1) Then
            Set r = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell(0, 2))
            Set s = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 2), rngCell(0, 3))
            lngMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(r)
            lngMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(s)
            m = Application.Match(lngMin, r, 0)
            n = Application.Match(lngMax, s, 0)
            raw.Cells(rngCell.Row, 10) = s.Cells(n).Offset(0, 6)
        End If

        lngPreviousRow = rngCell.Row
        Set r = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell(0, 2))
        Set s = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 2), rngCell(0, 3))
        lngMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(r)
        lngMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(s)
        m = Application.Match(lngMin, r, 0)
        n = Application.Match(lngMax, s, 0)

    Else
        Set r = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell(0, 2))
        Set s = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 2), rngCell(0, 3))
        lngMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(r)
        lngMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(s)
    End If
Next rngCell

Cells(lngPreviousRow, 10) = s.Cells(n).Offset(0, 6)
```

End Sub
[image]

So, in short, I need the last Net Value, `Column I`, based on the end date of each contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, depending your set up - you should post your whole code if it doesn't work. (Also watch out for non-unique max values.)

```
Dim n As Long, enddate, r As Range

Set r = Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell.Offset(0, 2))
enddate = WorksheetFunction.Max(r)
n = Application.Match(enddate, r, 0)

raw.Cells(rngCell, 10) = r.Cells(n).Offset(0, 5)
```

Comment: I added the whole code, with your edits added.  I am unsure how to fix the rest of it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem - does the code not work or produce unexpected results?

Comment: Well the first IF statement works only for contracts that are 1 year.  However the other lines are for Columns C and D, which is a different function.  I just copied the other function into this new function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your question was about finding the position of the max value in a range. If there is another problem, perhaps you should post another question.

Comment: `Application.Match` doesn't seem to be working. Error Type Mismatch

Comment: When that happens, what is the value of `enddate`? Are there any error values in your range?

Comment: Yes the error is with `enddate`, it is grabbing the value from `C2`, instead of the max at `D10`, in this example.

Comment: Your code seems to be going down column A and then checking the max of offset(0,1) and offset(0,2) which is column B and C? Also A10 is empty so Len(rngcell)=0 and your If statement will not be evaluated any further.

Comment: I edited my orignal post, it seems to be working for the most part, but only for the contract, and subsequent contracts it pulls the second to last number, not the last number.  Also it willnot work for one line contracts, ie. 1 year.