# VBA - Set Range from Max in range 2

Tags: vba, excel

I edited my orignal [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079162/vba-set-range-from-max-in-range), it seems to be working for the most part, but only for the contract, and subsequent contracts it pulls the second to last number, not the last number. Also it will not work for one line contracts, ie. 1 year.  This works only for the first contract.

The subsequent contracts are differentiated by the `Column A`. Where a new contract number begins. The goal is to have the last value from `Column I` for each contract. For example, the contract that is the area `A11:L15`, the value in `J11` should equal the value in `I15`. And this should be true for later contracts including contracts that are only one year like `A126` in the second image

[image: Top]
[image: One Year].

If someone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long, rngCell As Range, rngRange As Range, _
lngMin As Long, lngMax As Long, lngPreviousRow As Long, _
raw As Worksheet, data As Worksheet, dLRow As Double, endDate As Double, _
r As Range, n As Long

lngLastRow = lastRow(column_to_check:=2)

Set raw = Worksheets("Raw")
Set data = Worksheets("Data")
Set rngRange = raw.Range(raw.Cells(2, 1), raw.Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 1))
dLRow = data.Range("A1", data.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

raw.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Insert
raw.Range("C:E").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

For Each rngCell In rngRange

    If Len(rngCell) > 0 Then

        If lngPreviousRow > 0 And (rngCell.Row - 1 <> lngPreviousRow) Then
            raw.Cells(lngPreviousRow, 10) = s.Cells(n).Offset(0, 6)
        End If

        If (rngCell.Row = 1) Or lngPreviousRow = (rngCell.Row - 1) Then
            Set r = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell(0, 2))
            Set s = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 2), rngCell(0, 3))
            lngMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(r)
            lngMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(s)
            m = Application.Match(lngMin, r, 0)
            n = Application.Match(lngMax, s, 0)
            raw.Cells(rngCell.Row, 10) = s.Cells(n).Offset(0, 6)
        End If

        lngPreviousRow = rngCell.Row
        Set r = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell(0, 2))
        Set s = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 2), rngCell(0, 3))
        lngMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(r)
        lngMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(s)
        m = Application.Match(lngMin, r, 0)
        n = Application.Match(lngMax, s, 0)

    Else
        Set r = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell(0, 2))
        Set s = raw.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 2), rngCell(0, 3))
        lngMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(r)
        lngMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(s)
    End If
Next rngCell

Cells(lngPreviousRow, 10) = s.Cells(n).Offset(0, 6)
```

Comment: If you're referencing a previous question, would you kindly include a link to that question?

Comment: @E.Merckx I have hyperlinked the word Post to my previous post.

Comment: You have posted two images that are not aligned in terms of columns. Can you post a single image where the columns are aligned? If in same sheet, hide some of the intermediate rows before screenshot.

Comment: @QHarr, The columns are correct for both, just the second image has wider column widths

Comment: Apologies for my ambiguous terminology. I am not saying they are wrong. Simply very difficult to follow as they are not aligned (have different widths). This difference in widths also obscures some text making it difficult to tell if the columns in the top pic have the same values as columns in the bottom pic for a given column.

Comment: @QHarr, I will fix that, thank you.

Comment: @QHarr, it should look better now

Comment: What differentiates contract from subsequent contracts? And also how does one determine one line contracts as it seems every line says One year contract for validity.?

Comment: @QHarr, This works only for the first contract.  The subsequent contracts are differentiated by the `Column A`.  Where a new contract number begins. 
 The  goal is to have the last value from `Column I` for each contract.  For example, the contract that is the area `A11:L15`, the value in `J11` should equal the value in `K15`.  And this should be true for later contracts including contracts that are only one year like `A126` in the second image.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and include that information rather than put in comments so others can easily find it.

Comment: K15 is text whereas J11 is numeric so is J11 actually supposed to be K15?

Comment: My apologies, I meant `I15`

Comment: Please show column I in image. If necessary, hide any irrelevant columns.

Comment: @QHarr, it is in the images, which are aligned as well.

Comment: Apologies.Tired!

Comment: So J11 should be 0 if set to I15?

Comment: @QHarr, Correct, however my code is grabbing `I14`, which is the issue.  And every contract below is doing the same thing. Except for one year contracts which are blank.

Comment: Here is an   example of some logic that would assign as we have discussed. https://pastebin.com/7vjwuQSG  You would need to amend the sheet name.

Comment: @QHarr,  I found a solution, thank you though

Comment: Great. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the first row of the contract to show the last contract value. Additionally, it appears that the contract description (column K) is consistent for a given contract. If I understand your question correctly, simply loop through the description to look for changes. Then input the value into the first unique cell corresponding to the given description.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("k2:k146")
Dim NextCell As Range

For Each Cell In Rng
    Set NextCell = Cell
    Do Until NextCell.Text <> Cell.Text
        Set NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Set NextCell = NextCell.Offset(-1, 0)
    If Cell.Offset(-1, 0).Text <> Cell.Text Then
        Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = NextCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: I apologize, I actually meant `Column I` I edited it in the post.  Also, This is one small example of a huge data file in which the data goes down to Row 56,000.  So I need a longer range.

Comment: Just increase the range as needed. Or use the range you've already defined. This will input the last value from `Column I` for a given contract block into the first cell in `Column J` for a given contract block. That's what it appears you are trying to achieve. If this is not what you're trying to accomplish, please edit your question to make it clear _what_ you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am currently away from my computer, but I will test it later. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it.  Thanks to @E.Merckx for helping point me in the right direction.  Although it wasn't exactly what I wanted, it works just fine for its purpose.

```
Sub NetValue()

Dim lngLastRow As Long, raw As Worksheet, data As Worksheet, rng As Range

lngLastRow = lastRow(column_to_check:=2)

Set raw = Worksheets("Raw")
Set data = Worksheets("Data")
Set rng = raw.Range(raw.Cells(3, 6), raw.Cells(lngLastRow + 1, 6))

raw.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Insert
raw.Range("C:E").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

For Each Cell In rng
    If Cell.Value <> "" Then
        Cell.Offset(-1, 4) = Cell.Offset(-1, 3).Value
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

[image: Final Product]

Thanks again!